# g++: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmax7219 linking error

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

If I try to compile my project, I get following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -larmbianio
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmax7219
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:12: all] Error 1
```

My folder structure looks as follows:
*/home/bsy139/project/*

```
> lib/
--> armbianio
---> armbianio.c
---> armbianio.h
---> armbianio.o (renamed to .a)
---> makefile
--> max7219
---> max7219.c
---> max7219.h
---> max7219.o (renamed to .a)
> bsy-pi.cpp
> classes
> classes.h
> LCDisplay.cpp
> makefile
> Sensors.cpp
```

The makefile looks like:

```
# the compiler: gcc for C program, define as g++ for C++
CC = g++

# compiler flags:
#  -g    adds debugging information to the executable file
#  -Wall turns on most, but not all, compiler warnings
CFLAGS  = -g -Wall

# the build target executable:

all: bsy-pi.cpp
    g++ -g -Wall -I/home/bsy139/project/lib -L/home/bsy139/project/lib -o bsy-pi bsy-pi.cpp -lpthread -lm -larmbianio  -lmax7219

clean: 
    $(RM) bsy-pi
```

I don't understand, why g++ can't find the two libs. The makefile of these two libs wanted to `sudo cp libarmbianio.a /usr/local/lib ;\ sudo cp armbianio.h /usr/local/include` but I dont have permission on the machine. I think what that does is, that I can use `#include <>` in the Code instead of `#include ""`

Do you have some ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you point out where in your folder listing you see a `libmax7219.a` or `libmax7219.so`, which the `-l` option looks for? I don't see it.

Comment: I renamed the compiled .o files into .a files, but the error is the same.

Comment: The issue is not that the filename is wrong. Painting over your car's "Toyota" logo, and writing "Cadillac" in its place does not turn your car into a Cadillac. Either this project was not built correctly, or you cannot link with it, like that. You'll have to read over the documentation and/or build instructions and figure out the correct way to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the subdirectories in the lib folder, `-L/home/bsy139/project/lib/max7219` for example. It does not do recursive lookups.

If you have an *.o file you can just add it directly to the linker arguments. I don't think adding it as a lib would work without having a proper *.a file. Note that there is a naming convention. If you add "-lmax7219" the linker is looking for "libmax7219.a".

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Alltought the previous error is gone now, I get `undefined reference to maxInit(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char)`. This function is implemented in max7219.c. My g++ cmd is: `g++ -g -Wall -I/home/bsy139/project/lib/ -L/home/bsy139/project/lib/ -o bsy-pi bsy-pi.cpp -lpthread -lm lib/armbianio/armbianio.o lib/max7219/max7219.o`

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `-L` option. No `-L` option will help you if the library does not exist anywhere.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That's what my second part is about...

Comment: @jank04 the *.o files are compiled with the same flags and they are current?

Comment: I forgot to delete this part. Now it looks like `g++ -g -Wall -o bsy-pi bsy-pi.cpp -lpthread -lm lib/armbianio/armbianio.o lib/max7219/max7219.o` but still having the "undefined reference" error

Comment: Did you try to move the *.o file directly behind the *.cpp file? I must admit that I'm currently unsure if order matters, the g++ example in the GNU docs do it that way

Comment: I mean like this `g++ -g -Wall -o bsy-pi bsy-pi.cpp lib/armbianio/armbianio.o lib/max7219/max7219.o -lpthread -lm`

Comment: @taronyu I looked up the makefiles for the two libs and found out, that `CC` was not specified, and therefore is compiled in c? I added CC = g++ and compiled it this way. Now the error is not present any more.

The order of g++ command parameters made no difference. I changed it to your recommended order

Comment: Then C++ didn't know about it (that's why you usually see `extern "C"` before function declarations in the headers in C code).